# Issue with acronym being only a math mode symbol in glossaries with xindy

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, xindy

I am using `glossaries` package to create a list of abbreviations. I need to use `xindy` because otherwise the character `\"{o}` breaks an acronym by being in the definition (and it sorts them better). However, I also use some acronyms that are just mathmode symbols such as `$\alpha$`. For some reason, when I have that as the acronym that should be displayed, no glossary displays at all. Taking out the symbol, using a non-mathmode symbol, or adding a normal character to the acronym all make it work just fine.  Here is a simple example that does not work for me (using `xindy` makes no glossary, not using `xindy` only gives one glossary entry).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{test}{$\alpha$}{this is a test word}
\newacronym{test1}{\AA}{\aa \"{o}this is a test word}

\begin{document}

This is an example \gls{test}. and again \gls{test1}.

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Using Latexian, the PDF is made with no fatal errors, though the makeglossaries returns this: `ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string`.

I saw other questions that had errors with using `xindy` with `glossaries`, but they mostly seemed to deal with foreign language support.  Any help would be appreciated.

One thing I just found to work (that I will probably do if I don't get a better answer, but I doesn't explain the error) is adding a non-breaking space after the mathmode symbol: `$\alpha$~` though this makes the abbreviation "wider" than it should be.

Comment: Have a look at the Q3 in the [Troubleshooting section](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:trouble) of the user guide.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thanks. I completely overlooked that. I posted my own answer below based on your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a comment by [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot), I looked over Q3 in the Troubleshooting section of the [user guide](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:trouble) as directed. You can simply define a sorting value as an optional argument right after `\newacronym` to avoid issues with special characters (and even make it sort better).

I fixed the code above and it works great now:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[sort=alpha]{test}{{$\alpha$}}{this is a test word}
\newacronym[sort=angstrom]{test1}{\AA}{\aa \"{o}this is a test word}

\begin{document}

This is an example \gls{test}. and again \gls{test1}.

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Simple fix that even makes it better sorted.